# AppCompatImage and SwitchCompat views aren't displaying at all on devices with Android 7.0

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-7.0-nougat

I  have ButtonBarLayout with 5 controls  inside. 
All controls  are  showing  ok on  devices  with  Android 4.4, 5.0, 6.0,

But  on  Android 7.0 I  don't  see any views at  all except last  one  (AppCompatImageButton). Just  see blank  panel with 1  control  in the end

```html
    <android.support.v7.widget.ButtonBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="@{presenter.onClickPlz}"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/button_main_group"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:setSelected="@{presenter.checkedPlz}"
                  app:srcCompat="@drawable/main_check_box_plz_selector" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/top_bar_label_sort"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="@{presenter.onClickOpen}"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/button_main_orders_all"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:setSelected="@{presenter.checkedOpen}"
                   app:srcCompat="@drawable/main_check_box_open_selector" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/top_bar_label_open"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="@{presenter.onClickMy}"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/button_main_orders_my"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:setSelected="@{presenter.checkedMy}"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/main_check_box_my_selector" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/top_bar_orders_label_my"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    app:setOnCheckedChangeListener="@{presenter.onScreenToggle}" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button_main_settings"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/button_height"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:onClick="@{presenter.onClickSettings}"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_help" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.ButtonBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution  found - it  is  beause  of  usage of  ButtonBarLayout  in  this  case. I've  replaced  it  to Linear  Layout  and   its  works.